# Is there any network test software we can use between a router and a server under it?

Tags: networking

There is a confronting problem we have, the server network speed is very low, I want to check the speed between the router and the server.

so is there any tools for recommend?

---

**EDIT-01**

it only affect the Ethernet. 
the Server under the router can be any type all I can accept.
The price is open, no matter this is free or costs.
I just want to test the network between router and the servers under the router, no relation to the commercial environment.

Comment: This question is too broad and unclear. Does it affect WLAN or Ethernet? Do you want software for Windows or Linux, or do you even need both? What price/license limitations do you have? Do you want to use the software in a commercial environment?

Comment: The answer to the question as you posed it, is "yes, there are recommendations". My guess is, that "yes" does not help you much. Maybe you want to ask a question in a way so that you get a helpful answer. Practicing this skill is useful, since you need it all your life long.

Comment: I would check all cabling with a Fluke network tester or similar device.